# Connecting BigQuery to Looker

Tags: google-bigquery, looker

I am new to Looker and am trying create a report from a dataset from Google BigQuery.

I tried following the [Looker doc](https://docs.looker.com/setup-and-management/database-config/google-bigquery#:%7E:text=Scroll%20down%20to%20the%20OAuth,your%20data%20in%20Google%20BigQuery.) but this does not seem to work for me perfectly. I followed the steps by first creating a project in BigQuery and then creating a service account and added a key to it. I However skipped the creating PDT part and further created a BigQuery connection in Looker. The connection runs well but I do not see the tables/view in my dataset on Looker end.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try using "SQL Runner" and test some queries from any of your tables from BQ?  because it runs you can add that to a "view"  https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/learning-lookml/sql-runner-create-queries

Answer (score 0):

You need to create models and views in Looker using LookML

Here is the next step for you :
https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/getting-started/model-development

With that, you will have explores and you can create your dashboard...

Answer (score 0):

When u have a connection first initialized, u then create your first project inside looker, its a step by step process but it will give u the option to use default views and explore created for you. If you have an existing project then u can create custom views by using sql runner or u can click on the '+' in the file browser > click on "create view from table" > check the tables u would like to make into a view

Here is a link to how model structure is layed out
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OWik44xHMqEbZB2tzwaehMaa1MGJ0dZD/view?usp=drivesdk

Hope this helped!